# Is any algebraic extension a subfield of a spitting field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $F \subset K$ be an algebraic field extension, is $K$ a subfield of a splitting field of $S=\{{f_i}\}_{i \in I} $ over $F$? I tried: Let $\{{u_i}\}$ be a $F$-basis of K, $\{{p_i}\}$ be its corresponding minimal polynomials ,can we deduce that $K$ is  a subfield of the splitting field of $\{{p_i}\}$ over $F$? I got somewhat confused about the underlying sets. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The algebraic closure is the splitting field for $S = \text{every single polynomial in F}$.

Comment: Is K embed in the algebraic closure of F?

Comment: So take the algebraic closure of K since it’s algebraic closed and algebraic over K hence algebraic of F,  it’s also an algebraic closure over F. Then it’s an algebraic closure of F containing K.

Comment: Use Zorn's lemma to show that K embeds into the algebraic closure of F https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733942/existence-of-extension-of-an-embedding-for-an-algebraic-extension-of-a-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zorn's lemma (see [Existence of extension of an embedding for an algebraic extension of a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733942/existence-of-extension-of-an-embedding-for-an-algebraic-extension-of-a-field)) implies that there is an embedding $K \rightarrow \overline{F}$.

Now, $\overline{F}$ is the splitting field for $S = \text{every polynomial in $F[x]$}$ , and $K$ is isomorphic to the image of the embedding in $\overline{F}$.